# Is $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ an essential subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Given $H$ subgroup of $G$, we say that $H$ is a essential subgroup of $G$ if, for every non-trivial subgroup $K$ of $G$ we have that $H\cap K$ is not the trivial subgroup.

An example is $\mathbb{Z}$, which is an essential subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$. I wonder, as $\mathbb{R}$ is a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, if $\mathbb{Q}$ is essential for $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the subgroup of $\mathbb R$ that has multiples of $\pi$ (or another irrational number)?

Comment: In general, no vector subspace is ever an essential subgroup (under AC).

Comment: @Gae.S.how's that?

Comment: Because under AC all vector subspaces have an algebraic complement.

Comment: @Gae Why AC? If $U\ne V$, then there exists $w\in V\setminus U$ and $\langle w\rangle \cap U=0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True... For some reason I was thinking only about $W\oplus H=V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the non-trivial subgroup $K$ of $\mathbb R$ that has integer multiples of an irrational number.

Then $\mathbb Q\cap K$ is the trivial subgroup.

This demonstrates that $\mathbb Q$ is not an essential subgroup of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So K is something like rational number times R-Q?

Comment: I was thinking of $K=\{...,-3\pi,-2\pi,-\pi,\color{blue}0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi,...\}$, with $\pi\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$

Comment: Well, perhaps inverse of $k\pi$ will generate sth like rational numbers times $\pi$?

Comment: I see. It’s not multiplication group or field